# Can this function be optimized to run in O(n) time using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

Here's the scenario.

The function takes in an array of n item weights and an array of q capacities. The objective is to find the number of items that each bin can hold, depending on its capacity.

I've written the following function but the problem I'm having is that it's timing out on very large input values. Check it out below:

```
def noItems(weights, capacities):
    number_of_items = 0
    result = []
    weight_sums = [sum(weights[0:w:1]) for w in range(1, len(weights) + 1)]

    for i in range(0, len(capacities)):
        for j in range(0, len(weight_sums)):
            if weight_sums[j] <= capacities[i]:              
                number_of_items = number_of_items + 1

        result.append(number_of_items)

        number_of_items = 0

    return(result)
```

Update: sample input and output

input weights: [2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7]

input capacities: [10, 20, 18, 1, 40, 4]

input constraints:
weights[i] > 1 and < 1000
capacities[i] > 1 and < 10^9

output: [3, 5, 4, 0, 7, 1]

How can this function be optimized to have a faster runtime, so that it doesn't time out on very large inputs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "optimal solution" and "faster runtime" are different things

Comment: Give a small set of weights and capacities, plus the desired result.

Comment: @RickJames made an update

Comment: @mangusta my solution is timing out on very large inputs. So I'm looking to see what can be done to prevent that.

Comment: `each bin can hold` is not clear enough. In you example 10=>3 - why? What about another entries?

Comment: @MBo the function cumulatively sums each weight in the array. So for the first bin of capacity 10, it can hold 2 + 3 + 5 weights, making that a total of 3 items.

The same is done for the other capacities.

Comment: Must each bin be filled to capacity?  Or should the weights be spread out so as to minimize the bins?  Or any filling technique will be "OK"?  The algorithms are radically different, both in complexity and speed.

Comment: @RickJames each bin should be filled to capacity as much is possible. Once the weight can fit, it should go in. Then the objective is to count the number of items that can fit in each bin.

Comment: @Zeno - Still ill-specified.  Must I walk through the list of weights in order?  (This will be O(N)  Or should I look through the list for, say, a weight=3 when there is room for exactly 3 in a bin.  (This is much slower.)   I have an algorithm that is nearly optimal with a coefficient of about 2.

Comment: @RickJames yes, you must go through the list of weights and capacities in the order in which they appear in the input arrays.

Comment: That sounds like a single pass over the weights, filling the "current" bin until the next weight won't fit, in which case, move onto the next bin.  O(N).  Only one `for` loop,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem in `O(nlogn)` time using binary search over cumulative weight list

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def noItems(weights, capacities):
    result = []

    # or you can use itertools.accumulate():
    weight_sums = [0] * (len(weights))
    weight_sums[0] = weights[0]
    for i in range(1, len(weights)):
        weight_sums[i] = weight_sums[i-1] + weights[i]

    for x in capacities:
        number_of_items = bisect_right(weight_sums, x)
        result.append(number_of_items)
    return(result)

we =  [2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7]
ca = [10, 20, 18, 1, 40, 4]
print(noItems(we, ca))
[3, 5, 4, 0, 7, 1]
```

`O(n)` is possible only for previously sorted capacities.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but the function is still timing out on large inputs.

Comment: Because of quadratic cumulative sums (I did not noticed this fact)

Comment: The cumulative sums are the issue? How so?

Comment: Edited with linear cumulative sums

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution worked. So the main issue was with how I was calculating the sum of the weights. I see now. Thanks much for your assistance.

Comment: No, both calculating the sum and seaching inside double for-loop were quadratic